# How to find cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How find Cell reference by searching dynamically into different sheets?

I have a "Rose" column in my summary sheet. I need to find that cell reference by searching all the sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3).

[image: Rst1]

That "Rose" column appeared in Sheet3 M2 cell. I need this M2 cell in my summary sheet.
hope it clears.

[image: R2s]

Could anyone help me how to get the result? Thanking you :-)

Comment: VBA might be a better option here.

Comment: I thought of doing with Cell, Indirect function but its not giving proper answer. @BigBen

Comment: Is the value always on Row 2?  Searching a Row/Column is much easier than searching an entire sheet…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value always appears in Row 2 (like in your screenshot), then you could try this:

```
="=" & IFERROR(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(E5, Sheet1!$2:$2, 0), 4, 1, "Sheet1"), IFERROR(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(E5, Sheet2!$2:$2, 0), 4, 1, "Sheet2"), ADDRESS(2, MATCH(E5, Sheet3!$2:$2, 0), 4, 1, "Sheet3")))
```

It will check through, one sheet at a time, to see if the Colour name is found, and return either the Address, or a `#N/A` error.  Then it will return the first non-error value.

If you want a slightly more complicated version that can be expanded to any number of Worksheets, then you can use a `REDUCE` function with `INDIRECT` — however, the `INDIRECT` function is rather slow and inefficient, so don't over-use it!

```
="=" & REDUCE(NA(), {"Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"}, LAMBDA(x, y, IFERROR(x, ADDRESS(2, MATCH(E5, INDIRECT("'" & y & "'!$2:$2", TRUE), 0), 4, 1, y))))
```

Just add any Worksheets you want to search to the array (`{"Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"}`), or even make it a reference to a Range/Table.

---

The `REDUCE` function takes an Initial Input Value, and an array of Action Values, then applies the same `LAMBDA` function to the 'Current' Value for each Action Value.  It is being used in the above, to return the first non-Error value.

E.g. The function `=REDUCE("Hello World", {"l", "q", "o", "r"}, LAMBDA(x, y, SUBSTITUTE(x, y, ""))` would replace the letters, by going through the following steps:

- Inputs: `"Hello World", "l"`; Action: `SUBSTITUTE("Hello World", "l", "")`; Output: `"Heo Word"`
- Input: `"Heo Word", "q"`; Action: `SUBSTITUTE("Heo Word", "q", "")`; Output: `"Heo Word"`
- Inputs: `"Heo Word", "o"`; Action: `SUBSTITUTE("Heo Word", "o", "")`; Output: `"He Wrd"`
- Inputs: `"He Wrd", "r"`; Action: `SUBSTITUTE("He Wrd", "r", "")`, Output: `"He Wd"`

And, so, the final result of the `REDUCE` function would be `"He Wd"`

Answer (score 1):

First try this [formula to get the colours dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOMHA.png):

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet3!$2:$2;TRUE;FALSE);UNIQUE(Sheet3!$2:$2;TRUE;FALSE)<>""))`

You can put that formula in your first sheet.

Make sure the sheet reference to the range and the row is correct (in this case *Sheet3!* and *2*).

Then apply this [formula and get the cell coordinates (references)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Asd.png):

`=CELL("address";INDEX(Sheet3!$2:$2; MATCH(B4; Sheet3!$2:$2; 0)))`

Make sure to put the E5 instead of B4 for your first sheet.

This way you will always get your colours and the references to the first cell dynamically.

Hope this helps!